# How to look for the solution of the following problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider the solution of the ODE $y'(t) = -y^3+y^2+2y$ subject to $y(0) = y_0 \in (0, 2)$. Then $\lim_{t \to \infty}y(t)$ belongs to
>
> 1. $\{-1, 0\}$
> 2. $\{-1, 2\}$
> 3. $\{0, 2\}$
> 4. $\{0, \infty\}$

We have $$\frac{dy}{y(y^2-y-2)} = \frac{dy}{y(y+1)(y-2)} = - \frac{dt}{1}$$ Further, we can write $$\bigg[ -\frac{1}{2y}+\frac{1}{3\left(y+1\right)}+\frac{1}{6\left(y-2\right)} \bigg] dy= - \frac{dt}{1}$$Integrating both sides we get  $$ \frac{(y-2)^{\frac{1}{6}}(y+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}}{y^{\frac{1}{2}}} = ce^{-t} $$The initial condition $y(0) = y_0$ implies $$\frac{(y-2)^{\frac{1}{6}}(y+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}}{y^{\frac{1}{2}}} =  \frac{(y_0-2)^{\frac{1}{6}}(y_0+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}}{y_0^{\frac{1}{2}}} e^{-t}$$ Similarly, 
Now on taking the limit, we get $y=2$ or $y=-1$. Is my solution correct? Is $(3)$ one more solution?

Comment: I am sorry but can you please elaborate?

Comment: But $y(0) \neq 0$ is also known.

Comment: well $y(0)=0$ and $0   \in (0,2)$

Comment: No $0 \notin (0, 2)$ as it is open.

Comment: Ok then it's different

Comment: You still have some problem with $y=-1$ and for $y=2$ since the denominator becomes infinite...

Comment: It is ok, in the sense that if the limit in question exists, $L$ say, then passing to the limit in the displayed relation leads to $$|L-2|^{1/6}\cdot |L+1|^{1/3} / |L|^{1/2}=0$$, so $L$ is either $2$ or $-1$. Please use absolute values in the relation. (Else $y-2$ has no root of even degree.)